# How to compare between two arrays in php?

Tags: php

What's the best way to compare both two arrays to each other in a foreach loop ?.

I have two arrays, languages ​​and contents and i want to check if the content is translated or not, If it is translated it will show the translated content.

**Contents Array**

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lang] => it
            [content] => Contenuto Italiano
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lang] => en
            [content] => English Content
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lang] => es
            [content] => Contenido Español
        )

)
```

**Languages Array**

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language_code] => it
            [0] => it
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language_code] => en
            [0] => en
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [language_code] => es
            [0] => es
        )

)
```

**Php**

```
   <?php foreach ($languages as $language): ?>
    <?php if ($language['language_code'] == $contents['lang']){ ?>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $contents['content']; ?>">
   <?php }else{ ?>

    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>">

   <?php } ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
```

**Error**

Notice: Undefined index: lang

Comment: $language['language_code'] == $contents[$index]['lang'] right ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php 

$contents = array(array("lang" => "it","content" => "Contenuto Italiano"),array("lang" => "en","content" => "English Content"),array("lang" => "es","content" => "Contenido Español"));


$languages = array(array("language_code" => "it", "0" => "it"),array("language_code" => "en", "0" => "en"),array("language_code" => "es", "0" => "es"));


foreach ($languages as $language): 
    $key = array_search($language['language_code'], array_column($contents, 'lang'));
 
    if(!empty($key) || $key === 0){
        // Content is available for language
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$contents[$key]['content'].' ">';
        
    }
    else{ 
       echo '<input type="text" value="" placeholder="'.$language['language_code'].'">';
    } 

endforeach;
```

Comment: It's working as expected, but only one things is the placeholder not works

Comment: It is working for me, maybe  you are checking on that input who have language content available

Comment: try this :
`echo '<input type="text" placeholder="'.$language['language_code'].'" value="'.$contents[$key]['content'].' ">';`

Comment: Sorry one question more, what is the function of this ($key === 0)?

Comment: `empty` function read 0 as a empty value and on $key=0 we have a language `it` content.

So $key ===0  will enter into the condition